# Pandas df.loc with regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a data set consisting of several csv files of nearly the same form. Each csv describes a particular date, and labels the data by state/province. However, the format of one of the column headers in the data set was altered from `Province/State` to `Province_State`, so that all csv's created before a certain date use the first format and all csv's created after that date use the second format.

I'm trying to sum up all the entries corresponding to a particular state. At present, the code I'm working with is as follows:

```
daily_data.loc[daily_data[areaLabel] == location].sum()
```

where `daily_data` is the dataframe containing the csv data, `location` is the name of the state I'm looking for, and `arealabel` is a variable storing either `'Province/State'` or `'Province_State`' depending on the result of a date check. I would like to eliminate the date check by e.g. conditioning on a regular expression like `Province(/|_)State`, but I'm having a lot of trouble finding a way to index into a pandas dataframe by regular expression. Is this doable (and in a way that would make the code more elegant rather than less elegant)? If so, I'd appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `filter` to get the columns that match your regex

```
>>> df.filter(regex="Province(/|_)State").columns[0]
'Province/State'
```

Then use this to select only rows that match your location:

```
df[df[df.filter(regex="Province(/|_)State").columns[0]]==location].sum()
```

This however assumes that there are no other columns that would match the regex.